# Selenium chrome runs but cannot download with the Message: Stacktrace:

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to download free pdf resource that are located in each individual webpages. I tried selenium and it worked for a few pages and then it just opens the next webpage but just cannot download and shows the message: Stacktrace.

The code that I used is below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait  # Import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


# Set up Selenium WebDriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.add_argument('--headless')  # Run headless if you don't need a browser GUI
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# Define the range of testpaperids
start_id = 88690
end_id = 88699  # Example end ID, adjust as needed

for testpaperid in range(start_id, end_id + 1):
    # Construct the URL with the current testpaperid
    try:
        url = f'https://www.testpapersfree.com/show.php?testpaperid={testpaperid}'
        driver.get(url)

        # Wait for the download to initiate
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
        download_link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/a')))
        download_link.click()

        time.sleep(30)  # Adjust the sleep time as necessary

        # Additional code may be required to handle the download depending on how the site manages it

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred on testpaperid {testpaperid}: {e}")

driver.quit()
```

This is message that I get. I've rechecked that every webpage is working and that the full XPATH is the same. I just can't get the last step going. Not sure if it is being blocked.

```
An error occurred on testpaperid 88690: Message: 
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver                        0x0000000100a12004 chromedriver + 4169732
1   chromedriver                        0x0000000100a09ff8 chromedriver + 4136952
2   chromedriver                        0x000000010065f500 chromedriver + 292096
3   chromedriver                        0x00000001006a47a0 chromedriver + 575392
4   chromedriver                        0x00000001006df818 chromedriver + 817176
5   chromedriver                        0x00000001006985e8 chromedriver + 525800
6   chromedriver                        0x00000001006994b8 chromedriver + 529592
7   chromedriver                        0x00000001009d8334 chromedriver + 3932980
8   chromedriver                        0x00000001009dc970 chromedriver + 3950960
9   chromedriver                        0x00000001009c0774 chromedriver + 3835764
10  chromedriver                        0x00000001009dd478 chromedriver + 3953784
11  chromedriver                        0x00000001009b2ab4 chromedriver + 3779252
12  chromedriver                        0x00000001009f9914 chromedriver + 4069652
13  chromedriver                        0x00000001009f9a90 chromedriver + 4070032
14  chromedriver                        0x0000000100a09c70 chromedriver + 4136048
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001a979bfa8 _pthread_start + 148
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001a9796da0 thread_start + 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, just found correction on XPATH.

Replace below code

```
download_link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/section/div[1]/div[2]/a')))
```

[image]

I have added screen capture for `end_id = 88699`, ran fine.

Comment: thanks. changed the XPATH as shown but a new message came up. 'Message: element click intercepted:...'

let me try to tinker more. It was funny that the original code worked for a few downloads and kept giving error messages after.

Comment: @SleepyDad - try Edge driver

Comment: Thanks!! edge driver works. I had to modify it further to use javascript to click the element. now I had to deal with the occasional pop-up ads.